# contact form 7 wordpress not sending mails when use recaptcha extension

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 in my word press website.

CF-7 Working properly but when I use Recaptcha extension with it, it shows error and not sending mails.

Comment: Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method.

Comment: Did you check following links :

http://www.technoreply.com/fix-failed-to-send-your-message-please-try-later-or-contact-administrator-by-other-way/
http://contactform7.com/faq/#After_submitting_the_form_I_get_an_error_message
http://limecanvas.com/fixing-contact-form-7-failed-to-send-your-message-error/

Comment: yes I did, but my forms are working normally without using recaptcha.It shows error only when I add google recaptcha shortcode in it- [recaptcha]

Comment: then you need to check google recaptcha plugin code.

Comment: Yes, thats also perfect.I followed these steps- http://contactform7.com/recaptcha/

Comment: Please check plugin code and find what's wrong with code.

Comment: Thanks Milap...I'll check

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old. But better late than never. Right? You might have already figured it out by yourself. But in case you or someone else runs into the same problem:

I just had the same problem. CF7 sent the mail without reCAPTCHA. When using reCAPTCHA, the verification said I'm human, but when clicking `Send` I got the same error message

> Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method.

However, after unsuccessfully trying to figure out whats wrong in the code or file / directory permissions, I **rechecked the API keys provided by Google** and saw my mistake.

Sometimes, the keys can have a dash `-` in them. So if you (like me) just double clicked the field to copy-paste the key, it will only copy a portion of it.

Like this one: `ltrnA15pKhyzPJU9sSvh6gh-nFEWvDgC`

If you double-click it, it will only copy the first part before the `-` like `ltrnA15pKhyzPJU9sSvh6gh`. And if you then use this key on your site, it will be invalid and you will get the error message.

So make sure you carefully copy **all of the key**.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my the solution that worked for me.

When I created the first recaptcha, I chose **invisible recaptcha and that's what generated the problem in the form**.

**I deleted the created recaptcha and created a new one with the type recpatcha v2.** I copied the keys and everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

google reCAPTCHA ver 2.x with contact form7 is  not working anymore as ver 2.x is deprecated. You should have to update the api key and site key for the google recaptcha. I had the same issue and I have updated the key but its not working. So finally I removed the reCAPTCHA tag from the form and its working fine and sending the email.

Answer (score 0):

reCAPTCHA is not working with contact form 7 so you can use 'Advanced noCaptcha & invisible Captcha' and add shortcode [anr_nocaptcha g-recaptcha-response]